# Fetching data from php file in Vite+React returns file code instead of desired content

Tags: php, reactjs, wamp

I have the following users.php file:

```
<?php
   echo "Hello World";
?>
```

Along with the following Landing.jsx file:

```
import {React, useState, useEffect } from 'react'

export default function Index() {
  const url = "./src/app/controllers/users.php"
  const [data, newData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(url)
      .then((response) => console.log(response))
  }, []);
  return (
    <>
    </>
  );
}
```

However, what my php returns is:

```
<?php
   echo "Hello World";
?>
```

Instead of it returning "Hello World"

Even when I open the file in my browser it shows the source code and not the result I want, however, this happens when running npm run dev from Visual Studio code, however, if I run just that file alone in WAMP, the php file runs perfectly and returns what I want, but then the Landing.jsx does not run properly it returns the code for my Landing.jsx file.

Comment: This is probably due to your WebServer which serves the PHP Code is not configured correctly. You need to tell the Webserver to serve the PHP files via php-fpm or mod_php, can you provide your webserver configuration? `npm run dev` is just the webserver for your js code, it does not run a php process to handle php files. WAMP does run a php process and serve them, try to run wamp on a different port then your npm webserver, and call the correct WAMP url (with the new port) in your JS code. This should work then

Comment: @Tobias the issue I was getting was that I did not have permission for CORS, so I just followed the steps in this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N4yUiQiTvwU

Comment: Ok, i think there was probably another issue too, because when you open the php file in the browser (like you wrote in the question) you do not trigger any CORS. Anyway, im happy the issue got resolved for you :)